# How to generalize this concrete class?

Tags: java

The below `@Override` annotation indicates that I am not overriding the method defined in the interface. How do I use generics with my concrete class so that it overrides the interface method?

```
public interface AInterface<T extends MyType> {

  void do(T thing)
}

public abstract class BaseMyClass implments AInterface {
  // other stuff
}

// AType extends MyType
public class MyClass extends BaseMyClass <AType> {

  @Overide 
  public void doThing(AType atype) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BaseMyClass` is implementing the rawtype of `AInterface`, you either need to extend the generic to the abstract class itself or define it:

```
public abstract class BaseMyClass implments AInterface<AType>
public abstract class BaseMyClass<E extends MyType> implments AInterface<E>
```

`BaseClass<AType>` (assuming you meant `BaseMyClass`) isn't actually giving you a `AInterface<AType>`

Comment: thanks, I will accept this answer when enough time has passed.